# Calculating distance between 2 points - confused about radians

Tags: coordinate-systems

Let me start by saying math is NOT my strong point - by a long shot. I was asked to write a program calculating which locations from a given list (the co-ordinates given in degrees) are within 100km of a specific point. I was told to use the first formula on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) to calculate distance since this is more of a programming exercise than a mathematical one.

I calculated the central angle using the latitudes and longitudes in degress then converted to radians to calculate distance.

The problem is that my distances all seem very small. Here's the first few:

> 0.71099,
>   2.71675,
>   2.65812,
>   3.13579

I'm really confused now about units and what exactly the output I'm getting means. I *think* this is a maths issue rather than a programming one but if I'm wrong please let me know and I'll ask this on Stack Overflow instead.

Also, I hope I got the tag right!

**update**

I'm using ruby  to write this program and here's my method

```
  def distance
    read_data_from_file

    office_lat = 53.3381985
    office_long = -6.2592576

    # get and store all the central angles
    @customers.each do |customer|
      lat = (customer['latitude']).to_f
      long = (customer['longitude']).to_f

      @central_angles << Math.acos((Math.sin(office_lat) * Math.sin(lat)) +
        (Math.cos(office_lat) * Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(office_long - long)))
    end

    # now calculate distance using d = r * central_angle
    # but we must convert central angles to radians first

    @central_angles.each { |angle| @distances << 100 * to_rad(angle) }

    puts @distances
  end
```

`read_data_from_file` is just a method that pulls up all the customer information from a text file. The second to last line calculates distances and pushes them to an array. I used 100 for radius because we're looking for customers based within 100km of the office.

Comment: Did you multiply by Earth radius?

Comment: Could you give us an example of the input, output and the code you wrote? Right now, it is unclear how we can help you / where you are going wrong.

Comment: @Mihir I've added my code. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Arentino no.. I wasn't aware I had to. Will try that and see if the output makes more sense.

Comment: I'm not an expert of programming languages, but are you sure that Math.acos gives its result in degrees? Or is it already in radians?

Comment: @Arentino I'm actually not 100% sure. I'll check that and get back to you.

Comment: I'v just seen [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Math.html) that Math.acos gives its result in radians. Moreover, in the $d=r\Delta\sigma$ formula, $r$ is Earth radius.

Comment: Ah! I see. I feel really silly. Thank you for that. I've just run my programme again and the results make much more sense! If you put this in an answer I'l be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be warned that `Math.acos` gives its output in radians, and in the same way `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` want their argument to be expressed in radians, not degrees. Moreover, in the $d=r \,\Delta\sigma$ formula, $r$ is the Earth radius.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be any two arbitrary points on a sphere with center $O$ & a radius $R$ such that $\angle AOB=\alpha$ then draw a perpendicular say $ON$ from center $O$ to the straight line $AB$ to obtain a right $\triangle ONA$ thus we have $$\sin \frac{\angle AOB}{2}=\frac{\frac{\text{(great circle distance)}}{2}}
 {\text{radius}}$$ Now, the shortest distance between A & B $$\text{great circle distance between A & B}=R\sin \frac{\alpha}{2}$$

Where, the angle $\alpha$ can be taken in degree or in radians.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it's very well explained but I was asked to use the first formula on that wikipedia page I linked to in my question. :(